# How to create a Light with the Python API in Blender 2.92

Tags: python, scripting, light

I want to automatically create a point light source, but I can't get my blender script to work.
Im using the latest blender version 2.92.
After loading the default scene and loading my my obj model, I first delete the original light and then create a new light source:

```
# remove default light    
bpy.ops.object.select_by_type(type='LIGHT')
bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)

# Create new light
lamp_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="Lamp", type='POINT')
lamp_data.energy = 1000
lamp_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Lamp", object_data=lamp_data)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(lamp_object)
lamp_object.location = (0, 0, 2)
```

In the Cycles viewport I can see that the light is illuminating my object, but when I render with F12 my object is just black, see the screenshot [image]
What am I missing here?

Comment: Check the layer, its one

Answer (score 9):

Recommended way is to use low level API calls. Create a new light data block using [`BlendDataLights.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataLights.html#bpy.types.BlendDataLights.new), create a new object using [`ObjectData.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.html?highlight=objects%20new#bpy.types.BlendDataObjects.new), link the light data block and add the object to the collection in context using [`CollectionObjects.link(object)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.CollectionObjects.html#bpy.types.CollectionObjects.link):

```
import bpy

# Create light datablock
light_data = bpy.data.lights.new(name="my-light-data", type='POINT')
light_data.energy = 100

# Create new object, pass the light data 
light_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="my-light", object_data=light_data)

# Link object to collection in context
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(light_object)

# Change light position
light_object.location = (0, 0, 3)
```

[image]